# Undo checkout and remove Publish Transaction rights to users

Tags: cme, gui-extensions

I need to provide undo check out and remove publish transaction rights to specific users without making them admin users. I am aware that if i make them admin users i cant deny some of the actions which are unwanted and hence don't want to make them as admin users.

What would be the best\optimal way to achieve this?

I have got ideas to develop custom page or use GUI extensions. I am not aware of GUI extension and if anything in that direction is there somewhere or basic things as well would help me learn about GUI extensions. TIA

Answer (score 2):

Basically as you have found out already the security model of SDL Tridion does not provide for this. So your only option would be to create a tool which is running as a Tridion System Administrator which users can call to do this function.

I'm not sure if this can easily be done in a UI extension, the extension model of 2011/2013 is heavily based on the current user, so the only option you have there is to create a separate service, which is called by the UI extension (where the service is running under an admin account, or an impersonation account which will impersonate an admin in its call).

All in all I think you are getting yourself into a lot of work trying to make this happen, where it will probably be less work educating some of your super users, so you can make then a full admin.